# POSTGRES retrieve data from 3 tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have 3 tables

- User(user_id)
- Subscription(user_id, movie_id, date)
- Movie(movie_id, title, type)

and I want to retrieve the date, title and type for a given user_id.

Any ideas how can I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: This sounds like the most basic of inner joins, you should probably start with a SQL tutorial of which there are many [sql-using-joins](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-using-joins.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just a simple join; with the given criteria, the `user` table has no relevance.

```
Select s.date, m.title, m.type
from subscription s
join movie m on m.movie_id=s.movie_id
where s.user_id=<user_Id>
```

Comment: thanks for helping. I'm still pretty new to sql :)